# How do I Install the android studio update?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I recently started using Android studio and sometimes it gives me a message that an update is available. When I click on 'More Info...' it redirects me to the following page:

http://tools.android.com/recent

Anyone know what steps to follow?

Comment: goto Help-> Check for Updates..

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio prompted me to update and auto-installed the update when I accepted. But the suggestion in the above comment to use Help>Check for update works too...